# Chromecast - receive playback error callbacks from iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, chromecast, google-cast

Is there a callback for failed media playbacks in the Google Cast iOS Framework? I wasn't able to find anything useful in the documentation or the sample apps on github.

Specifically, I'm looking for load errors of HLS streams... So in case CORS isn't properly configured, the parsing of `*.m3u8` files fails, I want the sender iOS app to know about.

This is the closest I have found:

```
- (void)deviceManager:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager didFailToConnectToApplicationWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)deviceManager:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager didFailToConnectWithError:(NSError *)error
```

However, if connecting to the device, and launching the receiver application succeed, these callbacks will never fire.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
 - (void)mediaControlChannel:(GCKMediaControlChannel *)mediaControlChannel didFailToLoadMediaWithError:(NSError *)error
```